# database connection pdo php test database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, pdo

```
    <?php 
    global $dbh; 
    $dbname='userdb' ; 
    $userlist_tbl="userlist_tbl" ; 
    try { $dbh=n ew PDO( "mysql:host=localhost", "root", ""); 
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        $dbname = "`".str_replace("`","``",$dbname)."`"; 
        $dbh->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname"); 
        $dbh->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
        $dbh->query("use $dbname"); $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
        PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
        $sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $userlist_tbl ( user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        user_fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        user_lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        user_idnum VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);" ; 
        $dbh->exec($sql); } 
    catch(PDOException $e) { 

} ?>
```

This is how i connect to my database and make table. I am using php pdo here. My problem is in connection with database when i tried to rename the database and log in using my login credential using the table userlist i can still login. I was expecting that i cant log in because i am not using the correct database name.How do i make an error handler that when i rename the database name i should blocked to log in?Any idea is appreciated

Comment: If you rename your user table and use the original name of that table to login, you can't after renaming. So there must me something else going on. Can you post your login script?

Comment: I mean the database name not the table name..the table is found in the database right?when i change the database name i can still log in i am expecting i cant.. Which log in code you want me to post the ajax request or the php code?